# How to automatically check if the subscription of the user has expired and to make changes in the model?

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a website, where the user chooses a plan that have diferrent durations such as 7days, 14days, 21days. However the plan does not get activated immediately. After the user completes the registation process he has to accept an agreement, and then depending on the type of plan he has choosen the expiration date is set from the date of acceptance, and a field **contract_status** is set True.

Now, I want to know how I can automatically check that the expiration date of a user has reached and set the **contract_status** of that user to false and then perhaps do some other stuff. But mainly I want to know how I can check subscription expiration automatically to set the field to False.

**models.py**
This is the model that has the fields to store the that date of acceptance, expiration and contract status

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contract_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_of_acceptance = models.DateTimeField(null= True)
    date_of_expiration = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**
This is the view that deals with the above model when the user accpets the agreement

```
if request.method == 'POST':
           agreement = Contract()
           
           if request.user.plan == '7days':
                agreement.user = request.user
                agreement.contract_status = True
                expiry = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
                agreement.date_of_acceptance = datetime.now()
                agreement.date_of_expiration = expiry
                agreement.save()

                
                # for the customers
                template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 2000, 'accept': agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
                email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [request.user.email],                                       # sender email
                )
                email.fail_silently = False
                email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
                email.send()

                #for the owners

                template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 2000, 'accept': agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
                email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Customer Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    ['owner-email'],                                       # sender email
                )
                email.fail_silently = False
                email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
                email.send()

                return redirect('contract')
           
           elif request.user.plan == '14days':   
               agreement.user = request.user
               agreement.contract_status = True
               expiry = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=14)
               agreement.date_of_acceptance = datetime.now()
               agreement.date_of_expiration = expiry
               agreement.save()

               # for the customers 
               template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 3500, 'accept': agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
               email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [request.user.email],                                       # sender email
                )
               email.fail_silently = False
               email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
               email.send()

               #for the owners

               template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 3500, 'accept': agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
               email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Customer Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    ['owner-email'],                                       # sender email
                )
               email.fail_silently = False
               email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
               email.send()
               
               return redirect('contract')
            
           else:
                agreement.user = request.user
                agreement.contract_status = True
                expiry = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=21)
                agreement.date_of_acceptance = datetime.now()
                agreement.date_of_expiration = expiry
                agreement.save()

                
                # for the customers
                template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 5000,'accept':agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
                email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [request.user.email],                                       # sender email
                )
                email.fail_silently = False
                email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
                email.send()

                #for the owners

                template = render_to_string('contract_email.html', {'name': request.user.full_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'plan': request.user.plan,'price': 5000, 'accept': agreement.date_of_acceptance, 'expire':agreement.date_of_expiration})
                email = EmailMessage(
                    'Copy of Customer Contract',                                   #subject
                    template,                                                      # body
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    ['owner-email'],                                       # sender email
                )
                email.fail_silently = False
                email.content_subtype = 'html'       # WITHOUT THIS THE HTML WILL GET RENDERED AS PLAIN TEXT
                email.send()

                return redirect('contract')

    else:
        return render(request, 'contract.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a permission class in which you have to check that the current date is greater than the expired date. If current date is greater set the contact status to false and return false otherwise return true.
**Here's the example code:**

```
def permission_method(user_subscription_time, current_time):
    if user_subscription_time < current_time:
        contract = Contract.object.get(user__username = request.user)
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: @Muhammand Daniyal,  how the current_time detects the current time automatically, like current_time = datetime.now() ?

Comment: ok, I shall try